# When and where to call super().__init__() when overriding QT methods?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

When overriding [virtual functions of QtWidgets](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QWidget.html#virtual-functions), in which cases should I call `super().__init__()`? And in which cases does its position make a difference?

Example:

```py
class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

   def keyPressEvent(self, event: QtGui.QKeyEvent) -> None:
        """Variant A: Top"""
        super().__init__(event)
        # my code

    def mousePressEvent(self, event: QtGui.QMouseEvent) -> None:
        """Variant B: Bottom"""
        # my code
        super().__init__(event)

    def showEvent(self, event: QtGui.QShowEvent) -> None:
        """Variant C: Without"""
        # my code
        ...
```

I'm asking this, because I noticed that in my grown code I have all three variants, and I don't notice anything not working or any difference. Are there any general rules or best practices I could/should follow?

Comment: @Alexander,  that's basically my question. Can/should I just remove them? Is this true for _all_ event methods? What about non-event methods?

Comment: @Alexander, honestly, I can't remember why I put them there. Probably I have seen it somewhere. It's my first Qt Project.
To me, it also does not seem trivial to answer. E.g. What if the parent classes method does something useful/important with the event? How would I know about it?

Comment: If it's as easy as: "The constructor needs it as early as possible, leave it away in all other methods", that would be a great answer to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `super().__init__(...)`, you are literally invoking the parent classes constructor method. This typically should only be done once for each instance of the child widget in it's own constructor (aka `__init__`) method, and should be the very first call made.

For example:

```
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # ....... everything else
```

In my experience, there shouldn't be any need for it to be called in any other method other than the constructor.

Since your examples are all dealing with events, you might actually be referring to other superclass methods.  For example if your widget handles an event, but you would still like to have the even propogated to it's parents then you would call the `super().eventmethodname(args)`.

For example:

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event: QtGui.QMouseEvent) -> None:
        """Variant B: Bottom"""
        # ...  your code here
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
```